# Best place for an import and export statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, import, export

Say I have a large JavaScript file (about 300-400 lines), where is the best position for an export statement.

1. The end of the file ?
2. The start of a file ?
3. Right after the variable or function that we want to export ?
4. or some other place ?

Please help me with the most efficient place for an export statement

Comment: How about on the declaration itself..  `export function xyz() {};  export const boo = 2;`

Answer (score 1):

I usually go by after every declaration you want to export. So **at the end of the file** but it isn't necassarily best practice, I don't think there is a best practice for this, just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Just in my opinion , I usually import a javascript module in the start of the file, and export a javascript module in the end of the file.

VSCode and TypeScript Language Server complements import declarations in the start of the file, so I follow it.

```js
export function module() {}
```

```js
function module() {}

export {
  module
}
```

I think both of the above two way is correct and not discomfort, but I **feel** discomfort about mixed the two export way, so I usually made the regulation to export the either way with eslint and I like the latter because the latter way is easy to rename in exporting.

By the way, in the context of importing large javascript module, I use dynamic import.

Answer (score 0):

I think I more often want to know whether an identifier is exported than what a file exports.  That suggests that `export const k = 1;` is better than `export { k };` at the end of the file.  YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

You can create separate module and export it one Js file.

**For example**

***testApp.js***

```
Class myApp {
 constructor() {

 }

 testFunction() {

  conole.log("Hello World!");

 }

}

export default myApp;
```

***testRootApp.js***

```
import myApp from './testApp.js';

const app = new myApp ();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (params) {

app.testFunction();

});
```

Above one is sample code structure which you can use based on your requirement.